# Use new value from context when it is updated

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I load my settings from the server:

```
import { Context, createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

export class AppSettings {
    buildName: string = '';
    authority: string = '';
    truthPortalApi: string = '';
    environment: string = '';
}

export const AppSettingsContext: Context<AppSettings> = createContext<AppSettings>(null!)

export const AppSettingsProvider: React.FC<{ children: JSX.Element }> = ({ children }) => {
    const [settings, setSettings] = useState<AppSettings>(new AppSettings())

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`${window.location.origin}/settings`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => setSettings(data))
    }, []);

    return (
        <AppSettingsContext.Provider value={settings}>
            {children}
        </AppSettingsContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

and then I use them:

```
...
export const AuthContext: Context<AuthService> = createContext<AuthService>(null!);

export const AuthProvider: React.FC<{ children: JSX.Element[] }> = ({ children }) => {
    let appSettings: AppSettings = useContext<AppSettings>(AppSettingsContext)!;
    const [authService, setAuthService] = useState<AuthService>(new AuthService(appSettings));

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={authService}>
        { children }
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
}

export function useAuth(): AuthService {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
}
```

However, something that uses auth via `let auth: AuthService = useAuth();` only gets the inital emty value. It doesn't get the real value after it's loaded.
Can this work in React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not updating the `authService` when `appSettings` change. This line only sets the initial value once (although it recreates a new `AuthService` on each render).

```
const [authService, setAuthService] = useState<AuthService>(new AuthService(appSettings));
```

You need a `useEffect` to create a new `AuthService` when `appSettings` change:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setAuthService(new AuthService(appSettings));
}, [appSettings]);
```

In addition, you should avoid creating redundant `AuthService` on each render by using lazy initial values function, which would only create the initial `AuthService` on mount:

```
const [authService, setAuthService] = useState<AuthService>(
  () => new AuthService(appSettings) // lazy initial value
);
```

**Example**:

```
export const AuthProvider: React.FC<{ children: JSX.Element[] }> = ({ children }) => {
    let appSettings: AppSettings = useContext<AppSettings>(AppSettingsContext)!;
    const [authService, setAuthService] = useState<AuthService>(
      () => new AuthService(appSettings) // lazy initial value
    );
    
    // update on mount and when appSettings change
    useEffect(() => {
      setAuthService(new AuthService(appSettings));
    }, [appSettings]);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={authService}>
        { children }
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

Comment: (TS) Type '() => AuthService' is not assignable to type 'void | Destructor'.
  Type '() => AuthService' is not assignable to type 'Destructor'.
    Type 'AuthService' is not assignable to type 'void | { [UNDEFINED_VOID_ONLY]: never; }'. C:\Work\Azure\FactFind\react\fact-find\tsconfig.json

Comment: Is there any documentatio for this?

Comment: Documentation for initializing using a function - https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState#avoiding-recreating-the-initial-state

Comment: Is it `useEffect(() => () => setAuthService(new AuthService(appSettings)), [appSettings]);` ?

Comment: Nope. That's a copy/paste mistake. Fixed.

Comment: Next problem: my oidc signing callback is now trying to use the user manager before the settings have loaded and threfore has empty string as the authority. I tried `useEffect(signinCallbacl, [authService]` but it gets called _before_ the settings have loaded. `useEffect` seems to be working like a `BehaviourSubject` that emits it's initial value to new subscribers? When the settings finally get set the `AuthService` still has the empty string for the authority

Comment: The `useEffect` is called on mount, and whenever it's dependencies change. Add a condition (`if` block) to to only call it when the settings are loaded. Your callback should also have the `authService` as a dependency.

Comment: It looks like in `useEffect` the value of `appSettings` doesn't get updated.

Comment: How do you say _only when the settings are loaded_? Check for `settings.Authority === ''`?

Comment: Any condition that you decide signifies loaded settings would do. You should probably check for `settings.Authority !== ''` (not equals).

Comment: So it looks like `useState` really returns an `Observable` and `useEffect` acts to subscribe to it. What a muddle.

Comment: You are trying to convert an angular service, that can self update, to react context using a state.

Comment: I'm not. I'm familiar with Angular and trying to reproduce my app in React because the company has chosen React. Finding React to be complete rubbish.

Comment: It's much better than angular in my opinion. Just different paradigms from angular. Your main issue is the need to create a new service instance for each change. Don't do that. Create a context, and in the body of the context use a state for the `AppSettings`, and create multiple function using `useCallback`. Your life would probably be easier.

Comment: Into my fourth day struggling with oidc login in React. Was done in a day in Angular.

Comment: I would have been in couple of hours with React :) Different paradigms.

Comment: Try https://www.npmjs.com/package/oidc-react, https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-oidc-context or this (old) article - https://medium.com/@franciscopa91/how-to-implement-oidc-authentication-with-react-context-api-and-react-router-205e13f2d49

Comment: The latter one is unusable because it's completely broken. I hadn't found `oidc-react`, but that gets be back to the original problem: it assumes that the settings are hard-coded but I need to get them from `/settings`.

Comment: Pretty sure this is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The package `oidc-client-ts` seems to be the least broken, but you have to wrap it like this in order to pass in the settings.

```
import { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { AuthContextProps, AuthProvider, hasAuthParams, useAuth } from 'react-oidc-context';
import { User, } from "oidc-client-ts";
import { AppSettings, useAppSettings } from "./appSettings";
import Loading from "./components/Loading/Loading";

import { NavigateFunction, useNavigate } from "react-router";

let url: string = `${window.location.origin}/`;

export const LocalAuthProvider: React.FC<{ children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[] }> = ({ children }) => {
    let appSettings: null | AppSettings = useAppSettings();

    let [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading((appSettings?.authority ?? '') === '');

    }, [appSettings]);

    // Copied from https://github.com/authts/react-oidc-context/blob/f175dcba6ab09871b027d6a2f2224a17712b67c5/src/AuthProvider.tsx#L20-L30
    let signinCallback = (_user: User | void): void => {
        window.history.replaceState(
            {},
            document.title,
            window.location.pathname
        )
    };

    return (
        <Loading loading={loading || (appSettings?.authority ?? '') === ''}>
            {loading || (appSettings?.authority ?? '') === '' ? (null) : (
                <AuthProvider //userManager={userManager} doesn't work, all other settings must be passed
                    authority={appSettings!.authority}
                    client_id={'truth_portal'}
                    redirect_uri={url}
                    silent_redirect_uri={`${url}silent-callback.html`}
                    post_logout_redirect_uri={url}
                    response_type={'code'}
                    scope={'openid profile offline_access truth_portal'}
                    loadUserInfo={true}
                    onSigninCallback={signinCallback}
                >
                    {children}
                </AuthProvider>
            )}
        </Loading>
    );
}
```